# I want to make my dropdown menu keyboard accessible?

Tags: drop-down-menu, accessibility

I have searched for making dropdown menu keyboard accessible and found some demos, But still it didn't satisfied me.

To view menu structure: http://www.heart.org/HEARTORG/GettingHealthy/GettingHealthy_UCM_001078_SubHomePage.jsp

Answer (score 1):

First off, it is not only about the menu being keyboard navigable, but also about making the menu itself keyboard accessible.

As stated by [WAI-ARIA](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria), it should be possible to identify regions of pages and enable keyboard users to easily move among regions, rather than having to press Tab many times. That's what ARIA's **landmark roles**: application, banner, complementary, contentinfo, main, navigation, form, search, tree, treeview, etc. are for.

Modern user agents offer ARIA Support: Firefox, Opera, Safari, Internet Explorer 8/9
JAWS, Window-eyes, NVDA, VoiceOver.

Web Accessibility eminence Steve Faulkner claimed in [a a 2009 blog post](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2009/07/wai-aria-implementation-in-javascript-ui-libraries/) that "A number of popular Javascript UI Libraries are in the process of adding WAI-ARIA support to their widgets and components". jQuery plans ARIA support starting in 2.0 but no support is provided yet for any working version; I have tested myself [Google Web Toolkit's Menu Bar sample](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwMenuBar) and it has ARIA support, allowing keyboard navigation. You can check your favorite Javascript library for ARIA support...

If you want to code the menu tree yourself, [this treeview example](http://oaa-accessibility.org/example/41/) by the Open Ajax Alliance may help you.

Comment: tree-view menu style example wouldn't help me out. I already took bunch of example like this , which are treeviews! Btw **Thanks** for the suggestions.